# Disable input option based in the class of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html generated by a prepopulated form in gravity forms:

```
<ul id="input_4_17" class="gfield_radio">
    <li class="gchoice_17_0">
        <input type="radio" tabindex="1" id="choice_17_0" name="input_17">
        <label for="choice_17_0">
            <img class="stock instock" id="gchoice_17_0">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_17_1">
        <input type="radio" tabindex="1" id="choice_17_1" name="input_17">
        <label for="choice_17_1">
            <img class="stock outofstock" id="gchoice_17_1">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_17_2">
        <input type="radio" tabindex="1" id="choice_17_2" name="input_17">
        <label for="choice_17_2">
            <img class="stock outofstock" id="gchoice_17_2">
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to disable inputs based on the stock status, that is the class of the img element. I can't put this class in the input, so I'm using this javascript to disable inputs based on the class of the image to disable inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('img#gchoice_17_0').hasClass('outofstock')) {
        $('input#choice_17_0').attr("disabled", "disabled").prop("checked", false);
    }
    if ($('img#gchoice_17_1').hasClass('outofstock')) {
        $('#choice_17_1').attr("disabled", "disabled").prop("checked", false);
    }
    if ($('img#gchoice_17_1').hasClass('outofstock')) {
        $('#choice_17_1').attr("disabled", "disabled").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

This works but I know this is not the best way to do this. I'm trying this code, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('img').hasClass('outofstock')) {
        var getIde = $(this).attr("id");
        $('input#' + getIde).attr("disabled", "disabled").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: Only one element can have a given id. You need to change the HTML and the logic.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it doesnt work? Did you try to console.log your `getIde` do you have right ID?

Comment: I've turn the image id in a class

Comment: Your `$(this)` refers to all document, put each loop there.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.outofstock').parent().prev().prop('disabled',true).prop('checked',false);
       });
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DwSPM/)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$('.outofstock').parent().prev('input:radio').prop('disabled', 1)
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WyYq/)

**Update :**

```
$('.outofstock').parent().prev('input:radio').prop({
    'disabled':1,
    'checked':0
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WyYq/1/)

Comment: You are my HERO! thanks a lot, now it's working and only with a few lines of javascript :D

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot...

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    $('img').each(function(index){
        if($(this).hasClass('outofstock')){
            var getIde = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#'+getIde).attr('disabled', 'disabled').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```